# Is there a way for optaplanner to continue the last best solution to the next calculation

Tags: optaplanner

I am using optaplanner 8.4.1 and constraint flow API.

Does optaplanner have a way to output the best solution to the problem based on simple constraints, and then input the solution into complex constraints to find the best solution? Can this speed up the time to the best solution?

Constraints are too complex and slow, especially when you use groupby and toList methods. My current logic involves the judgment of consecutive substrings.

For example: there are 10 positions and 10 balls with serial numbers. The color of the ball can be white, black or red. At this point, you need to line up 10 balls into 10 positions. It is required that the white balls must be piled together. The white balls have a range of 4 to 6; the position here is the planning entity, and the ball is the planning variable. Here we need to calculate how many continuous white balls there are. Constraint flow currently only supports 4 bases, so it can only be judged in the form of groupBy and toList

Comment: I agree that groupBy to a list will slow you down. That said, would you mind elaborating on what you mean by "judge the results yourself"? toList() should really only be used as a last resort when all else fails, and I have a suspicion that you are trying to accomplish something that will be inherently slow.

Comment: My constraints are too complex. I want to get the data of the solution to control the movement. Groupby and tolist are too slow. They will give me a lot of empty data and duplicate data. I don't need these data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that as a single solver currently, but you should be able to do that by running 2 Solvers (with a different `SolverConfig`) one after another. For you example you could have `BasicConstraintProvider` with the hard constraints and a `FullConstraintProvider` that extends the basic one and adds the soft constraints.

That being said, I'd first invest time in improving the **score calculation speed** (see info log or a benchmark report), to avoid such workarounds all together. That number should be above 10 000.

Also, `FIRST_FEASIBLE_FIT` might be intresting to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your problem, but what I am doing is:

1. Run solver for some time (maybe even using less number of constraints), then serialize solution it provides
2. Run solver second time (could be with different settings) providing previous solution as a problem, it will keep looking for better one.

It works for me in version 8.30.

Maybe it will help somebody else.